# Generating new ID: Getting actual IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a login module in php and facing some problem generating ids.

On the registration part, I need to generate an unique ID per user. I thought I'd be able to generate this ID by incrementing the last ID in the database by 1, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
    $user = $_POST['post_username'];
    $pass = $_POST['post_password'];

    function generateID(){

    $aux = mysql_query("SELECT usr_id FROM users");

    $i = 0;

    $resulArray = mysql_fetch_row($aux) or die("Error fetching!");
    $n = mysql_num_rows($aux);

    $b = $resulArray[$i];
    $c = $b;
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i = $i +1){
        $b = $resulArray[$i];
        if($b >= $c) $c = $b;
    }

    return $c + 1;}
```

Here's my MySQL structure:

```
username -> String
password -> String
usr_id   -> int
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do this. It's unreliable and cannot address race conditions. Just use an auto-increment primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE users
   id unsigned int auto_increment primary key,
   ...
);
```

then

```
INSERT INTO users (id, ....) VALUES (null, ...)
```

and

```
$userID = mysql_last_insert_id();
```

This is inherently reliable, handles race conditions, and will guarantee unique ids for this table. You won't need any custom verification, just auto-increment the id field and let MySQL take care of the ids.